# Solving binary quadratic form equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, quadratic-forms

$$ \ln (x^2 + y^2) + {2x^2\over x^2 + y^2} = 0$$

I solved the easy way by setting each term equal to zero:

$$ {2x^2\over x^2 + y^2} = 0$$
$$ 2x^2 = 0$$
$$x=0$$

Then:
$$\ln (x^2 + y^2)=0$$
$$\ln\, (\,y^2)=0$$
$$y=\pm 1$$

I'm looking for other integer solutions for this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are no others.

If $x$ is a non-zero integer, and $y$ is any integer, then $x^2+y^2$ is a positive integer, so $$\ln\left(x^2+y^2\right)\ge\ln(1)=0.$$ Thus, since $\frac{2x^2}{x^2+y^2}$ will be positive, $(x,y)$ cannot be a solution to the equation in such a case.

---

Note that since the equation's left-hand side is undefined (so that the equation fails to hold) when $(x,y)=(0,0).$ Thus, excluding this possibility, the equation becomes equivalent to $$\left(x^2+y^2\right)\ln\left(x^2+y^2\right)+2x^2=0.$$ The graph [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%5E2%2By%5E2)*ln(x%5E2%2By%5E2)%2B2*x%5E2%3D0) plots the solutions to this equation.